# Get active Div id in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I want to customise back key on my android device using jQuery mobile app.

For this firstly I get a active page id and work according to them.

Like this

```
if($.mobile.activePage.attr("id") == "page"){
}
```

but now I use multiple div and app will show and hide div at run time.

Is there any way in jQuery that will find active div id at runtime? Or is there any other way?

```
$.mobile.activeDiv.attr("id")..
```

Something like this. ?

Comment: What is an active DIV to you? You need to be more precise.

Comment: i use this http://jsfiddle.net/3RJuX/ in my app.Now how can i know that which div is currently active on screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/MN2N6/

```
alert($.mobile.activePage.find('.content_div:visible').attr('id'));
```

Comment: Thank you so much. i just want it